# PostgreSQL equivalent of Oracle bulk insert

Tags: oracle, postgresql, rspec

Trying to re implement this oracle bulk insert to postgres equivalent.

Currently have:

```
          a.each do |b|
            params << [nil, b.value]

            inserts << %{INSERT INTO table(a, b, c, d)
            VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4); }

          end

          sql = inserts.join 
          ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
            # insert
            ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_update(sql, 'table', params)
          end
```

What would a similar implementation using activerecord / postgres look like?

I am getting the below error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
  #   ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
  #   LINE 4:                 VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5, :a6, :a7, :...
  #                                   ^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql uses the syntax `$1`, `$2`, etc for parameter placeholders. Replace the Oracle `:a1`, `:a2`, ... with `$1`, `$2`, ...

SQL has a concept of prepared statements, where you supply the statement with placeholders instead of actual values. You can then execute the statement one or more times supplying the parameters each time. This is more efficient because the server only has to parse, analyze and plan your query once.

In answer to your comment, it looks like you are preparing a string containing multiple `INSERT` statements concatenated together. Instead you need to prepare only one `INSERT` statement and then execute it multiple times, once for each row of parameters.

Unfortunately I don't know enough about ActiveRecord or even Ruby to be able to suggest how to rewrite your code to achieve that!

By the way, this is not what I would call a 'bulk insert'. The fastest way to get data into postgresql is usually via the [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) command.

Comment: Awesome.  This worked.  Now the issue is that I have multiple rows in "params".

ActiveRecord::Base.connection.exec_update(sql, 'table', params)

What is the best way to implement a bulk insert for postgressql / activerecord in a similar way?

Comment: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement
       : INSERT INTO